# Аналог strtotime() на C++

Tags: c++, unixtimestamp

Нужно преобразовывать строки вида "10 January 16 14:10:09" в Unix time "1452427809". Как это работает на С++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть такая функция [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html), которая как раз должна подойти для Ваших нужд.

Пример кода для Вашего случая:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    struct tm tm = { };
    strptime("10 January 16 14:10:09", "%d %b %y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
    std::cout << mktime(&tm) << "\n";
}
```

[Результат:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/b1TrXj5o9lsnXMXt)

> ```
> 1452402609
> ```

Как было замечено в комментариях, функция не входит в Стандарт C++, и является POSIX функцией. Т.е. в некоторых реализациях, например под Windows, она может быть недоступна. В этом случае можно использовать исходный код [отсюда](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libc/time/strptime.c?rev=HEAD).

Comment: Но она, увы, не входит в стандарт C++... Правда, выполнять анализ руками еще страшнее :)

Comment: @Harry угу, это POSIX.